# XSD aware XML to XML dynamic transformation

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an input XML something like:

```
<Root>
 <FirstTag>
    <Attribute1>value1</Attribute1>
    <Attribute2>value2</Attribute2>
    <FirstTagValue>Test</FirstTagValue>
 </FirstTag>
</Root>
```

and I want to convert it using java to

```
<ns:Root xmlns:ns="http://my.comp.com/root" xmlns:ns1="http://my.comp.com/child">
 <ns:FirstTag Attribute1="value1" Attribute2="value2">
    <ns1:FirstTagValue>Test</ns1:FirstTagValue>
 </ns:FirstTag>
</ns:Root>
```

I have an XSD defined for output XML. So, basically I want to check the input XML tags against the XSD, then dynamically build my output XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSD to validate that an XML document adheres to its rules.

An XSD does not itself transform one XML document into another.  For that, use XSLT.

Comment: may be i did not ask my question correctly.. i want to convert it using java but without generating jaxb objects... if we can validate an xml against xsd in java then this should be possible.. i mean i need a way to check if field is xml tag or an attribute.. something like java refelections,, if i can find that then i think its possible to build output xml as per XSD defined..

Comment: You could use various XML parser libraries in Java, but XSLT is the ideal way to transform XML to XML.

Answer (score 0):

If the only information you want to use from the schema is to decide whether to convert a child element to an attribute, or to keep it as a child element, then you could do it like this using facilities in Saxon (you'll need Saxon-EE for schema-awareness).

First, create an SCM file from your schema (run `com.saxonica.Validate` with the `-scmout:schema.scm` option). An SCM file is an XML representation of the schema component model, which is much more amenable to processing than the original source schema.

In the SCM file, for an element like `FirstTag` you will find something like this:

```
<scm:element id="C141"
                name="FirstTag"
                targetNamespace="http://something"
                type="C392".../>
```

and then you can find the corresponding type:

```
<scm:complexType id="C392"
                    base="C344"
                    derivationMethod="extension"
                    abstract="false"
                    variety="mixed">
      <scm:attributeUse required="false" inheritable="false" ref="C1075"/>
      <scm:attributeUse required="false" inheritable="false" ref="C1076" default="no"/>
      <scm:attributeUse required="false" inheritable="false" ref="C1077"/>
```

and for each attributeUse you will find an attribute declaration like:

```
<scm:attribute id="C1075"
                  name="select"
                  type="C156".../>
```

so in XSLT, you can write a function to test whether a given element has a given attribute like this (ignoring namespaces, and assuming that $SCM is a global variable holding the SCM document):

```
<xsl:function name="f:elementHasAttribute" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="element" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="attribute" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="decl" select="$SCM//scm:element[@name=$element]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="type" select="$SCM//scm:complexType[@id=$decl/@type]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="atts" select="
     for $u in $type/scm:attributeUse return 
      $SCM//scm:attribute[@id=$u/@ref]"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$atts/@name = $attribute"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and now you can process elements like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="attributeChildren"
      select="*[f:elementHasAttribute(current()/local-name(), local-name())]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$attributeChildren">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy-of select="* except $attributeChildren"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't tested the code but the design should certainly work.